# Error in function cv2.calibrateCamera

Tags: python, opencv

I tried running this code from OpenCV docs for camera calibration after modifying a few lines.

```
for fname in images:
    i =i+1
    print(str(i))
    img_train = cv2.imread(fname,1)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_train,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    ret, corners = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gray,(9,9),None)

    if(ret == True):
        objpoints.append(objp)
        corners2 = cv2.cornerSubPix(gray,corners,(11,11)(-1,-1),criteria)
        imgpoints.append(corners2)
        cv2.drawChessboardCorners(img_train, (9,9), corners2,ret)

    cv2.imshow('Train',img_train)
    cv2.waitKey(500)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

grey = cv2.imread('GoPro/GOPR4176.JPG',0)
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints,imgpoints,grey.shape[::-1],None,None)

np.savetxt("CAMERA_MATRIX_FOR_VIDEO.txt", mtx)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (nimages > 0) in calibrateCamera, file /home/atul/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp, line 3357
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gopro2.py", line 53, in <module>
ret, mtx, dist, rvecs, tvecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(objpoints,imgpoints,grey.shape[::-1],None,None)
cv2.error: /home/atul/opencv/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp:3357: error: (-215) nimages > 0 in function calibrateCamera
```

Why does this error occur?

Comment: The error occurs because it does not get any images. Check that the image is being loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is objp ? Likely you are using different size of objp. You have to define 
objp = np.zeros((n*m,3), np.float32)
objp[:,:2] = np.mgrid[0:n,0:m].T.reshape(-1,2)

where n and m are size of grid (circular or chess board, 4x11, 7x6 etc)